# Can someone help me converting a SQL Query into LINQ expression?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Can someone help me converting the following SQL Query into LINQ expression?

```
select student.StudentID,
       student.FirstName + ' ' + student.MiddleInitial + ' ' + student.LastName, 
       student.OpenDate,     
       acct.Balance    
from Student student
inner join 
(Select StudentID, Sum(Amount) as Balance 
from Account 
Group by StudentID) as acct on student.StudentID = acct.StudentID
```

---

The following LINQ expression works! Thank you so much Phil!!!

```
var results = (from s in Students     
          join a in Accounts on s.StudentID equals a.StudentID     
          group a by new                  
             {s.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.MiddleInitial, s.LastName, s.OpenDate}             
             into z     
             select  new     
             {   StudentID = z.Key.StudentID,         
                 FirstName = z.Key.FirstName, 
                 MiddleInitial = z.Key.MiddleInitial, 
                 LastName = z.Key.LastName,         
                 OpenDate = z.Key.OpenDate,         
                 Balance = z.Sum(a=> a.Amount)       
             }
             );
```

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't mix presentation logic into your SQL queries. The query should return the parts of name as three fields and it should be on the receiving application how to render them.

Comment: You are correct, thanks. I will modify the query to return only parts of names and take care of the format in the presenetation layer.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try?

```
var stu = 
    from s in db.Students
    join a in db.Account on s.StudentID equals a.StudentID
    group a by new 
                {s.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.MiddleInitial, s.LastName, s.OpenDate} 
            into z
    select new 
    {   StudentID = z.Key.StudentID,
        FullName = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",z.Key.FirstName, z.Key.MiddleInitial, z.Key.LastName),
        OpenDate = z.Key.OpenDate,
        Balance = z.Sum(a=>a.Amount)
    };
```